# How to use a Zustand store in Jest in place of props

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, zustand

I removed some props that were being passed down from another component and placed this state in a Zustand store which broke my jest test.

How do I use these store state values in my test?

These are the props that are being used currently for my jest test.

```
const setup = (props = {}) => {
    const setRtfCount = jest.fn();
    const setBrtfCount = jest.fn();

    const defaultProps = {
        storeSearchFlag: 1,
        rtfCount: 0,
        brtfCount: 0,
        setRtfCount,
        setBrtfCount,
    };
    const utils = render(<StoreTable {...defaultProps} {...props} />);
    const instance = utils.container.firstChild;
    const rerender = (props) =>
        utils.rerender(<StoreTable {...defaultProps} {...props} />);

    return {
        ...utils,
        instance,
        rerender,
        setRtfCount,
        setBrtfCount,
    };
};

it('does a fresh load and sets rtfCount and brtfCount if the storeSearchFlag is over 1', async () => {
    const { instance, setRtfCount, setBrtfCount } = await setup({
        storeSearchFlag: 2
    });
    await waitFor(() => expect(scrollTo).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2));
    const table = instance.querySelector('div[aria-label="table-mock"]');
    expect(table).toHaveTextContent('RTF');
    const rows = table.querySelectorAll('div[aria-label="data-row"]');
    expect(rows).toHaveLength(3);
    expect(setRtfCount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    expect(setBrtfCount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    expect(setRtfCount).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(3);
    expect(setBrtfCount).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(0);
});
```

Here are the props that I removed and placed into a store.

```
rtfCount: 0,
brtfCount: 0,
setRtfCount,
setBrtfCount
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

```
const defaultCounts = {
    rtfCount: 0,
    brtfCount: 0,
    rtfPageNumber: 0,
    brtfPageNumber: 0
};

const setup = (props = { counts: {} }) => {
    let { counts, ...overrides } = props;

    const refusalClicked = jest.fn();
    const handleKeyPress = jest.fn();
    const setRtfCount = jest.fn();
    const setBrtfCount = jest.fn();
    const setRtfPageNumber = jest.fn();
    const setBrtfPageNumber = jest.fn();
    const clearSearchData = jest.fn();
    const setNoSearchResults = jest.fn();

    mockUseCountsStore.mockImplementation(() => ({
        ...defaultCounts,
        ...counts,
        setRtfCount,
        setBrtfCount,
        setRtfPageNumber,
        setBrtfPageNumber
    }));

    const defaultProps = {
        refusalClicked,
        searchLoading: false,
        handleKeyPress,
        recordType: 'RTF',
        storeSearchNumber: 5560,
        storeSearchFlag: 1,
        clearSearchData,
        setNoSearchResults
    };
    const utils = render(<StoreTable {...defaultProps} {...overrides} />);
    const instance = utils.container.firstChild;
    const rerender = (props) => {
        let { counts, ...overrides } = props;
        mockUseCountsStore.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
            ...defaultCounts,
            ...counts,
            setRtfCount,
            setBrtfCount,
            setRtfPageNumber,
            setBrtfPageNumber
        }));
        utils.rerender(<StoreTable {...defaultProps} {...overrides} />);
    };

    return {
        ...utils,
        instance,
        rerender,
        refusalClicked,
        handleKeyPress,
        setRtfCount,
        setBrtfCount,
        setRtfPageNumber,
        setBrtfPageNumber,
        clearSearchData,
        setNoSearchResults
    };
};
```